# Show any straight line is irreducible

Tags: polynomials, ideals, irreducible-polynomials

Show that any straight line in $\mathbb{F}^{n}$ is irreducible, where **F** is an infinite field.

I know **V**($ax+b$) would be a variety that represents any straight line and then V is irreducible if **I**(V) is prime but I'm not too sure where to go from here.

Answer (score 0):

Use that lines can be parameterised.

[Cox Little and O'Shea: *Ideals, Varieties and Algorithms*](https://books.google.com/books?id=yCsDO425PC0C)

> Proposition 5. If $k$ is an infinite field and $V \subset k^n$ is a variety defined parametrically
>   $$x_1 = f_1(t_1,\ldots,t_m), $$
>   $$\vdots$$
>   $$x_n = f_n(t_1,\ldots,t_m),$$
>   where $f_1, . . . , f_n$ are polynomials in $k[t_1, \ldots , t_m ]$, then $V$ is irreducible.